# How can I say the order in one chart is not like the order in another chart?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

I'm trying to write a clear, beautiful, formal sentence about the order of data sets in this chart:

[image: fig1]

As you can see, the order of the values for "non-curved" data points (from higher to lower)is light-blue, green and blue.

And the order of the values for data points in the set called "curved with radius 0.2916" is light-blue, blue and green.

I want to say that they are not compatible. Is this a good word for what I'm trying to say?.

What would be the best (clear, beautiful and formal) way to say it? Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say.  Can you take a crack at such a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the word 'compatible', which means that two things or people can function together harmoniously.

You're trying to say that the order of one data set is not the same as the order of the other. If the light blue was the smallest in the non-curved set you could say that the order was reversed, but it's not. As it is, there's no pattern to describe.

It would be a good idea to identify which quality you're ordering when comparing the data sets. It's the order of the value corresponding to the uu values from lowest to highest that is different. So:

> The order is not directly related to relative values of uu for the non-curved set but it is directly related in the curved set.

or

> The order with respect to the value of uu is different between the two sets.

But if you just want to use one formal word to say they're different, you could say

> The order of the two sets is not identical.

or

> The order of the two sets is dissimilar.